# Prove that $g(x)=-5f(x)$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I need some help in solving this question:

Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Prove that $g(x)=-5f(x)$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$.

My attempt: Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ for any partition $P$ with $||P||<\delta$ and $S$ any sample points, $|RS(f,P,S) - I|< \frac{\epsilon}{|-5|}$.

So $|-5||RS(f,P,S) - I|< \epsilon$
 $\Rightarrow$ $|-5||\sum f(s_i)\Delta x_i - I|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $|\sum (-5)f(s_i)\Delta x_i - (-5) I|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $|g(x) \Delta x_i - (-5)I|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $RS(g,P,S) - (-5) I|<\epsilon$.

Hence, $g(x)=-5f(x)$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$.

Does my work look good so far?

Comment: In  the sentence starting with 'So, I think you forgot to cross-multiply the Í'by 5.

Comment: @user99680 No, I don't think so. I forgot to put it in modulus.

Comment: You're right, my bad.

Comment: Position->Partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f is continuous g is Riemann integrable then $f o g$ is Riemann integrable. note that composition of two Riemann integrable function is need not be Riemann integrable.